# Replacing every occurrence of a char except when it's in a pattern

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk, grep

I'm trying to do something but i'm not sure how to do.  I have a file of 23 Mo :

```
: (blah  
  :aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa  
  (bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
: (bloh
  cccccccc
  dddddddd

...
```

And so on.
What il like to do is remove all line jump **"\n"** except when \n is followed by **": ("**
So the final file would be:

```
: (blah  :aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa (bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb        
: (bloh  cccccccc  dddddddd
...
```

I have several idea to do it, the first one is:
- remove all **"\n"** with sed
- replace all **": ("** by **"\n: ("**
but the problem is the file is 23MO and I don't know how to manage this on one line file of 23mo.

A second idea but still I don't know how to do at all, is:
- remove every **"\n"** except when it matchs in the pattern **"\n: ("**
I don't know how.
I'm limited to bash perl sed grep and awk as ressource.
I'd really love to have your inputs.

Have a nice day.

Comment: Did you try your first idea, what were the problems with it?

Comment: What's `Mo`? `Monday` ? `MegaObjects` ?

Comment: @Endoro: Megaoctet, same as Megabyte

Comment: I'll run a few test and choose the one I prefer as official response if they all work :-)

Comment: @cmh the first idea does not work because sed does not like to open a 23MB long file line and I get an error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can do most of the work by defining awk's record and field separator variables:

```
awk 'NR==1 {next} {$1=$1;  print ": (" $0}' RS=': \(' FS='\n' OFS="" filename
```

Since the file begins with our defined record separator, there is an empty first record, which we skip.

Same program, a bit more readable

```
awk '
    BEGIN {FS="\n"; OFS=""; RS=": \("; prefix=": ("}
    NR==1 {next} 
    {$1=$1; print prefix $0}
' filename
```

Comment: Why not just just a single block with the conditional `NR>1`

Comment: That one is working great, I just need a way to truncate space but I think I'll figure it out.

Comment: Before the print statement, `gsub(/[[:space:]]+/, " ")` would do it.

Answer (score 4):

One method with `awk`:

```
$ awk '/^: [(]/&&NR>1{printf "%s",ORS}{printf "%s",$0}END{printf "%s",ORS}' file
: (blah  :aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa  (bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
: (bloh  cccccccc  dddddddd
```

Comment: Adding ORS is a nice touch, but probably unnecessary

Comment: I don't know why or how but it put my file on a same line.

Comment: @Kiwy that means your example input is not representative of your actually input.

Comment: It works on the example not on my working copy, I do not undertand what's the problem with my example...

Answer (score 4):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;$!N;s/\n([^:])/\1/;ta;P;D' file
```

Remove every `\n` except when it does not match the pattern "\n:"

Comment: I'll test that but as the script will be running on a Checkpoint modifiy RHEL I'm not sure that it's GNU sed :-)  Edit: By the way after testing it run without ending and no output is generated.

Answer (score 2):

I found another code for GNU sed.

```
sed  -n ':k;N;/\n:\s*(/{$!P;$p;D};s/\n/ /;$p;bk' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You did mention perl, so...

```
perl -pe 'print "\n" if $.>1 && /^: \(/; chomp if ! eof' file
```

or for v5.10 and above

```
perl -pE 'say "" if $.>1 && /^: \(/; chomp if ! eof' file
```

Comment: I test both of your scripts and they are making the file on one line only and not separate properly

Comment: @Kiwy, darn it I missed a colon in the regex. I'll fix it.